# obfsproxy crashes

Tags: obfsproxy

```
 sudo obfsproxy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/obfsproxy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('obfsproxy==0.2.13', 'console_scripts', 'obfsproxy')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/obfsproxy/pyobfsproxy.py", line 183
    except ValueError, err:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

1. obfsproxy{1,2,3} should all be dead and buried (okay, obfs3 still gets use but there's no reason you should be wanting to run obfs2...)
2. [obfsproxy4](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/tree/obfs4proxy) should be preferred for pluggable transports (*and* it's backwards compatible).
3. It's intended for python2 (specifically >=2.7) see: [#11190](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11190)

Bonus question: *Oh No! Why Are You Running It As Root?!*